# WPF DataVisualization Chart DataPointStyle Affects Legend Colors

Tags: .net, wpf, charts

I am using the DataVisualization Charting control to display a Stacked Area Chart. I would like to style the data points which appear on the chart. However, when I create a Style and assign it to the DataPointStyle, the legend markers are no longer the same color as the data they represent. They appear as a single color. I do not even have any styles yet defined in the style.

My code is

```
Dim stackedDataPointStyle As New Style(GetType(AreaDataPoint))

Dim cas = New Charting.StackedAreaSeries
cas.SeriesDefinitions.Add(New SeriesDefinition With {.DependentValuePath = "Hrs", .IndependentValuePath = "Weekday", .ItemsSource = _data.Values, .Title = job.ProjectName, .DataPointStyle = stackedDataPointStyle})

Chart1.Series.Add(cas)
```

[image: Incorrect Legend Colors]

If I remove the .DataPointStyle = stackedDataPointStyle, the legend markers are the correct corresponding colors to the chart areas.

Any help someone could provide would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I have also tried using the following, where the Style is redefined with each new series that is added.

```
Dim cas = New Charting.StackedAreaSeries

For Each job In _data
    Dim stackedDataPointStyle As New Style(GetType(AreaDataPoint))
    cas.SeriesDefinitions.Add(New SeriesDefinition With {.DependentValuePath = "Hrs", .IndependentValuePath = "Weekday", .ItemsSource = _data.Values, .Title = job.ProjectName, .DataPointStyle = stackedDataPointStyle})
Next

Chart1.Series.Add(cas)
```

The results are still the same.

Comment: You should use a different data point style for different series definitions. In the current code you use the same style for all series definitions.